# Updating a utility to show the date last modified

Tags: python, user-interface

I am creating  SIMPLE LOG FILE UTLITY gui using python. Each time I run the program, the source file is copied to the destination file and the source file is deleted. When the utility is started I want the display to say "The Log file was last updated (date goes here)". I have created a function named `modification()` using `os.path.getmtime`. How do I use this function to display the date?

Comment: You can convert the time value returned by `os.path.getmtime()` into a `time.stuct_time` with `time.localtime()`, and then convert that into a string using `time.strftime()`. Displaying that depends on the unspecified GUI you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answers on the Python docs :

The getmtime function (http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) returns the number of seconds

Thanks to the Time module (http://docs.python.org/library/time.html), you can convert the number you get into local time (localtime()) or UTC time (with gmtime()).

Then, you just have to display it with your GUI toolkit as Dhaivat Pandya pointed out.

Regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

Make it return the date as a string, and then display it with your GUI toolkit.